# How to get attribute of nearest neighbour of polygons from a points layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, proximity

I have 2 layers, one of polygons and one with points. Both have some attributes.
For each polygon, I would like to take one attribute of points layer from the nearest point and put it in a field of polygons layer.
Is there a way to do this with QGIS 3?

Comment: Hi forumSIG pal ! Look at the [refFunctions plugin](https://geogear.wordpress.com/2014/11/13/reffunctions-v1-0/), use `geomnearest('point_layer_name', 'point_layer_field_name_to_retrieve')`.

Comment: How do you define "nearest"? Distance between point and centroid, distance between point and border, distance between point and centroid within polygon, distance between point and weighted centroid?

Comment: @Erik if I can have the choice, it will be great. But if I have to choose now, I would say between point and centroid.

Comment: Hvae you tried NNjoin plugin? check https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/